# What is the meaning of this statement of a probability distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working through some notes and trying to understand a piece of the following statement:

Suppose that the bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the square $[0,1]^2$, that is the joint probability distribution function of (X,Y) is given by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1 \space\text{if}\,0\lt x\lt 1 \text{  and} \space 0\lt y \lt 1\\
0 \space \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$.

What exactly is the function saying exactly?
Shouldn't it be assigning probabilities to $(x,y)$ pairs as it's a pdf ?
Is it saying that the probability that an (x,y) pair lying in the square is 1 if $0\lt x\lt 1$ and $0\lt y\lt 1 $ ?

I get the feeling that my understanding of density functions needs a bit of reinforcing....

Comment: He is assigning densities to the pairs.  Density 1 for all the pairs in the unit square.

Comment: If you graph this, it's basically a cube with a volume of 1.  You can deduce that the two random variables are independent and identically distributed.  The probability density at any ordered pair inside the square is the same.

Comment: $\Pr[(X,Y)\in A]=\int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y)d(x,y)$ for any measurable $A\subset [0,1]^2$. In this simple case, for uniform $f$, $\Pr[(X,Y)\in A]$ is just the area of $A$

Comment: @KellyLowder so geometrically f(x,y) is giving the height about the x,y base which is a square? But isn't this then saying that the probability of any (x,y) pair occurring is 1 so long as the pair is in the area??

Comment: @stochasticmrfox, No, the probability of any particular pair occurring is 0, since there are infinitely many possible outcomes.  The probability density is 1 everywhere.  So if you imagine a small region around any given point in the square, the probability of landing in the region is equal to the area of the region.

Answer (score 1):

On the unit square $]0,1[\times ]0,1[$, this function is $1$. Outside this unit square, in the rest of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, this function is $0$.

Note that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy = \int_{]0,1[^2} 1 dxdy = 1$$ since the Lebesgue measure of the unit square is $1$, thus this really is a density function.

The probabilities are given by

$$\mathbb{P}\{(X,Y) \in A\} = \int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy, \quad A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$

Or more concretely,

$$\mathbb{P}\{(X,Y) \in A\} = \lambda(A \cap ]0,1[^2), \quad A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Do you have that backwards? $f_{X,Y}$ is a probability density function, and is not a cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\ f_{XY}\ $ is the *density function* of the distribution, not the distribution.  The probability that $\ (X,Y)\ $ belongs to any particular (measurable) subset $A$ of the Cartesian plane is given by
\begin{align}
P\left((X,Y)\in A\right)&=\iint_\limits{A}f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy\\
&= m\left(A\cap[0,1]^2\right)\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ m(S)\ $ denotes the area (i.e. Lebesgue measure) of a set $S$.

The joint *distribution* function, $\ F_{XY}\ $, of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ is given by
\begin{align}
F_{XY}(x,y)&=P\left(X\le x, Y\le y \right)\\
&= m\left(\left((-\infty,x]\times(-\infty,y]\right)\cap[0,1]^2\right)\\
&=m\left((-\infty,x]\times[0,1]\right)m\left((-\infty,y]\times[0,1]\right)
\end{align}